# Why does the --crypto-mode no longer work in Synergy?

Tags: synergy

When I try to specify a crypto mode for Synergy on the command line using `--crypto-mode`, I now get this error:

```
Unrecognized option: --crypto-mode
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In our 1.4.13, we dropped the `--crypto-mode` arg, since we removed all crypto modes except CFB. So right to solve this, just don't use the `--crypto-mode` arg.

We added this arg in version 1.4.12 - it was so that users could in theory add an extra level of randomness to make a hacker's life harder. However, this was a bad idea for a few reasons:

1. Security by obscurity is not a good cryptography practice.
2. 3 of the 4 crypto modes were [easily cracked](https://defuse.ca/cracking-synergy-bad-cryptography.htm).